# How to fit frame to curve?

Tags: gnuplot

[image: Current output]

As you can see the curve ends at about 3/4 of the width but the frame continues.
I want the frame to end where the curve ends.
The code for this was:

```
set terminal png transparent size 300,150
set output 'day.png'
set xdata time
set timefmt "%s"
set format x "%k:00"
set xtics 0, 43200 rangelimited
set ytics 5, 5
plot 'day.txt' using 1:2 title "`date +%H:%M`"  with lines lw 2
```

When `rangelimited` is omitted, the size of the frame stays the same, but the lower line is solid until the end.

Also note, that as you can see the data is coming from a file so I do not know the range of the X axis.

So to repeat the question: How do I tell gnuplot to fit the (right) side of the frame to the end of the curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following command:

```
set autoscale xfix
```

more infos with

```
help autoscale
```

greetings
Raphael